# General availability of Google Cloud Composer on Europe-West-3

Tags: google-cloud-composer

is there anybody who knows when google-cloud-composer will be available on europe-west-3 ?

Thanks a lot for your help,

Answer (score 1):

The global expansion of Cloud Composer is underway. Composer just added support for Mumbai and additional regions are planned in Q1 2018 and Q1 2019. By the end of Q1 2019 Cloud Composer will likely roll out with new regions as they are made available.

At the moment, `europe-west-3` is likely to be available in early 2020.